# Understanding meteor tutorial

Tags: meteor

I am having hard time grasping the template concept here. Here is the code which i copied from [meteor tutorial](https://www.meteor.com/tutorials/blaze/templates)

```
<ul>
  {{#each tasks}}
    {{> task}}
  {{/each}}
</ul>
```

Now the questions.

1. I got the that `{{#each` is `meteor` directive/keyword whatever we say. but what is `tasks` here. Does `#each` goes into the .js (simple-todos.js in this case) to find what `tasks` is ?
2. Secondly, I get it that `{{>task}}` is outputing the text (using template) which was saved in js file. What i am assuming here is `{{#each <template_helper_object>}}`and then for each object, we are calling `task` template. Now the question is, how this task template is aware of corresponding task object ? Am i making it confusing ?

Comment: I'd recommend going [here](https://www.discovermeteor.com/encyclopedia) and reading the articles on templates.

Answer (score 0):

1. `#each` is an iterator. `tasks` is a helper that gets looked at from you .js file

   ```
   tasks: [
     { text: "This is task 1" },
     { text: "This is task 2" },
     { text: "This is task 3" }
   ]
   ```
2. `{{>task}}` is calling a function that returns the template instance `task` and populates data dynamically from the `tasks` helper.

Work through the rest of the tutorial and you'll see how it works with dynamic data and collections